# Test and production on different iOS SDK

Tags: ios, xcode, sdk

I have "xcode-4.6.3" on my mac and i use "iOS SDK 6", when I want to test it on device that "iOS 7" as operating system, it gave errors. If i upload the app on apple store, those who have "iOS 7" devices can download and run the app?
I am a beginner in iOS and i need your help, thank you.

Comment: It'd help if you post the errors given.

Comment: the error given when testing that i need the newest sdk to match the os on the device. but my question i have an app developped on xcode 4.6.3 and sdk 6, if i uploaded on apple store, any device can download the app and run it?

Comment: Since February 1st, All apps submitted to the app store must be compiled against the iOS 7 SDK (Using the latest Xcode). See https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=12172013a. If you are getting errors when trying to compile your application against the iOS 7 SDK for the first time then it might be worth you updating your question with more information related to the errors you are getting.

Comment: @liamnichols: you should add this as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since February 1st, All apps submitted to the app store must be compiled against the iOS 7 SDK (Using the latest Xcode).

See developer.apple.com/news/?id=12172013a for more info.

If you are getting errors when trying to compile your application against the iOS 7 SDK for the first time then it might be worth you updating your question with more information related to the errors you are getting.